# Completed Task List question

Tags: task-list

I'm trying to understand the logic behind the columns for Task Lists.
These Columns are for % Completed and Complete.

I am using SharePoint 2013 on Windows.

At first I thought the %Completed was automatically updated when the task was completed from the timeline. But I don't think that's the case.

Then my coworkers thought that the person just manually updates the %Complete.  Now I don't believe this is true.

**Am I correct in that, the %Complete column only goes from 0% to 100% depending on if the Completed column is selected?**

And if that is the case, if I select the Completed box making %Completed 100% then the next person logging into the Task List will see that 100% completed... is this correct?

Thanks for your help.

[image: Screen Shot of Task List with Completed columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more logic Microsoft programmed:

- `% Complete` is set to 0 when you set the `Status` to `Not Started`
- `% Complete` is set to 100 when you set the `Status` to `Completed`
- `% Complete` is set to 50 when you set the `Status` to **any other value**
- The checkbox sets % Complete to 0 or 100

The behaviour comes from Code behind of the Checkbox field and from the CSR file clientemplates.js which is set as a JSLink on every view

If you assign a JSLink to a ListView WebPart **all** assigned JSLinks on the View are ignored and you loose the checkbox in the View

*disclaimer: I might have missed something in the described behaviour above,

pulled my hair out on this some years ago*

Comment: Is the % Completed something a SharePoint 2013 should update manually?

Comment: Yes, the behaviour I described was programmed by Microsoft, it updates the PercentComplete field, if you want to control it yourself (manually) you have to **not** use the default Microsoft fields PercentComplete and Status

Comment: The way my coworker have it, (if I understand correctly), you have to go into the Task Item, Item View, change the percentage and it changes. However, it will go to 100% when the completed column is selected and back to 0% once the completed column is not selected. So it doesn't work. Therefore, it really is an all or nothing function, from 0% to 100%

Comment: That is the 4th bullet you describe and I wrote: ''The checkbox sets % Complete to 0 or 100"  That is the code behind code Microsoft added to the Completed Column